# Displaying š in textbox

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to display the character š in a textbox, but it's only displaying the other letters in the word. I'm grabbing data from a DB and, using json_encode, sending it via xmlhttp.responseText. When doing alert(xmlhttp.responseText) the character is coming up as \u009a, but in Unicode it says U+0161 is for š. Maybe this is the reason it's not displaying correctly? I'm using Cpanel, and I've set all encodings for the DB to utf8, but it won't let me change the encoding of the actual page from ascii. Maybe this is causing the letter to not be displayed?

Main page code:

```
function loadDoc()
{
   var xmlhttp;

   // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   // code for IE6, IE5
   else
   {
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
         alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
         var a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
         document.getElementById("textbox").value=a.first;
         document.getElementById("textbox2").value=a.second;
         document.getElementById("textbox3").value=a.third;
         document.getElementById("textbox4").value=a.fourth;
         document.getElementById("textbox5").value=a.fifth;
         document.getElementById("textbox6").value=a.sixth;
      }
   }

   xmlhttp.open("GET","loadTextBox.php?id=4",true);
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

loadTextBox.php code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json");

---Placeholder for correct DB login info---

$result = $mysql->query(---Placeholder for correct SQL query---);

while ($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $queryResult[] = $row->present_tense;
}
$textboxValue = $queryResult[0];
$textboxValue2 = $queryResult[1];
$textboxValue3 = $queryResult[2];
$textboxValue4 = $queryResult[3];
$textboxValue5 = $queryResult[4];
$textboxValue6 = $queryResult[5];
echo    
json_encode(array('first'=>utf8_encode($textboxValue),'second'=>
utf8_encode($textboxValue2),'third'=>utf8_encode($textboxValue3),'fourth'=>
utf8_encode($textboxValue4),'fifth'=>utf8_encode($textboxValue5),'sixth'=>
utf8_encode($textboxValue6)));
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding in the line

```
$mysql->query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

inside `loadTextBox.php` after connecting to the DB and before the SQL query and removing the lines with **utf8_encode** fixed it.

Comment: When you edited my answer, how did you make "loadTextBox.php" highlighted and in the same line as text?

Answer (score 1):

The U+009A is the SINGLE CHARACTER INTRODUCER, which is very similar to Caron as you can see here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/9a/index.htm.

The U+0161 is the real Caron Unicode code ( http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/161/index.htm )

Comment: I understand that, but that doesn't help me solve my problem.

Comment: "but it won't let me change the encoding of the actual page from ascii" - Why not? Why should the display change before the document encoding does? You'll never display Russian or Chinese in an ascii page, why should this be any different? Because it kinda, sorta looks like a latin character?

Comment: In Cpanel it does not let me change the file encoding. When I click save and then open it again it goes back to the ascii setting.

Comment: It seems like the code for the loadTextBox.php file forces the Cpanel encoding to be us-ascii.

Answer (score 1):

Either your db or the json encoder you are using is **saying** that it has data as Unicode, but is actually outputting [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252);